Retrieving Shopify App Access Token Once Admin Completes OAuth
I've created a Shopify App using the remix template, now when the store merchant approves the scope of the app upon install I want to take the accessToken and send it to AWS Secrets Manager with their Store URL.
Everything else for the app is built, it's really just improving the user experience by automatically modifying theme files that remains, which is where the accessToken is required to complete.
I have found this file, which from watching guides and looking through the files seems to be the most relevant.
import type { LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  await authenticate.admin(request);

// Access Token > AWS Logic

  return null;
};

The problem I have is I can't get the shop name. (and I'm not sure if I even have to...) but to convert the sessionToken to a access token I need it.
Basically I want to modify this function to get the accessToken and store name and send it to AWS when the admin authenticates.
Any help would be great!
There is a Prisma schema that mentions the accessToken
model Session {
  id            String    @id
  shop          String
  state         String
  isOnline      Boolean   @default(false)
  scope         String?
  expires       DateTime?
  accessToken   String
  userId        BigInt?
  firstName     String?
  lastName      String?
  email         String?
  accountOwner  Boolean   @default(false)
  locale        String?
  collaborator  Boolean?  @default(false)
  emailVerified Boolean?  @default(false)
}

So it looks like awaiting the auth should result in the above session attributes being populated. So I should then be able to request the accessToken right? Keen to get some insight.
Tried the below by combining some of the steps from some guides I've seen, it doesn't work, but seems close???
import type { LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {

  const sessionToken = await authenticate.admin(request);
  console.log("Session token:", sessionToken);

  const shop = sessionToken.input_data.shop.domain;


  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenForShop(shop);

  console.log("Access token:", accessToken);
  return null;
};

async function getAccessTokenForShop(shop: string): Promise<string | null> {
  const session = await prisma.session.findUnique({
    where: {
      shop: shop,
    },
  });
  return session ? session.accessToken : null;
}

The shop const I got from a guide for getting the shop name from a client side checkout session, I doubt it's the same for getting the store URL from the admin session. Again any info would be great, I can't find it anywhere.

Hey, it's unclear what you want! A shop name, a way to get the access token, or populate the session data after the completion of OAuth?!
Would you please clarify that first so that we can help?
Does the database get populated after the OAuth completion?

Any of the above basically, if I have the shop url and sessionToken I can get a accessToken. Or if there's a way to get a accessToken straight away that solves the issue.

Does the session table get populated with necessary data after installing the app?
If not, we must populate the session table before calling a method such as "getAccessTokenForShop(shop: string)."
Please be specific about your needs. The code example you shared indicates that the session data (which includes accessToken) is already in the database, and in that case,
You can fetch the shop URL or name using a simple GraphQL shop query and then use it in the desired method.

I think I actually found the solution within the remix app template, it looks like Shopify have opted to train developers by building a demo app rather than documenting exactly how that works within the remix app template. Once I've checked that it works I can update here on whether that solved this issue. I would assume it will be helpful for others who were looking for dev docs on this rather than following the app template "build your first app" guide. But maybe I just tried to jump too far ahead.

here is what I found https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/build/build?framework=remix
You'll notice that the functionality to fetch the store URL is already in the app template, so you don't have to build it, which is great, but I think that information on what exactly has been built, and how you need to interact with it should still live in dev documentation rather than solely relying on an example to infer what you should do.

If I am getting it correct, then you are trying to get the access_token from remix app.
It's pretty simple to get:
In the app._index.tsx you can create a new loader and do something like this
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    const { admin,  session, } = await authenticate.admin(request);
    console.log(session);
}

This session object contains the access_token.
In the Remix template by default the access_token is Offline Access Token so it stays valid till the user uninstalls the app.
I hope this helps.
